# Summation of CDFs

Tags: statistics

1. Is $F(x_1)+F(x_1+x_2)$ possible be further integrated into $F(y)=F(x_1)+F(x_1+x_2)$, where y is some number. Ps: I know the definition of CDF, I am just wondering is there particular theorems can do this.
2. When apply the quantile function $F^{-1}$ to $F(x_1)+F(x_1+x_2)$, can it be further simplified? I.e., is $F^{-1}(F(x_1)+F(x_1+x_2))$ equals to?

Comment: No.  Note that the range of any CDF is $\subseteq[0,1]$ and summing two CDFs take it outside to $[0,2]$.

Comment: Right! Does it have any alternative forms?